# Certificate error when using IP address after upgrade from WS 2003 to 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

When I access my site using the IP address (the domain name still works fine) I get a certificate error.  This is after upgrading from Windows Server 2003 to 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The certificates are associated to a specific hostname. So if you try and access your site with just it's IP address the certificate won't match.

You can use a service such as [SSL Shopper's SSL Checker](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) to see what hostname is associated with a given certificate.

#### example

[image: ss of ssl checker]